# how can I delete an alarmclock I used the AlarmClock class not AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

When I use the `AlarmManager`to add a clock I cannot receive  the broadcast after closing my app.  For this reason, I use the `AlarmClock` class to add a clock.  But when I add a clock using the AlarmClock class, I can not cancel or delete the clock. 
How can I remove a clock added by the AlarmClock class?

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
                    alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, content);
                    alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_DAYS,mday);
                    alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, mhour);
                    alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, mminuti);
                    alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
                    alarmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(alarmIntent);
```

Comment: I think this actually add's an alarm which your default alarm clock app will pickup. Try opening it and see if it's there - let me know if not and I will look into it further.

Comment: yes only this way can let the clock  touch off, i use my app add a clock then Even if my app not open it still can effective  but now i want use code to delete the clock

Comment: i have search many articlescraps ,best result is intent to the system setting UI then manual delete it, i want let it more easy just use java code